# How to send a list of data from controller to a modal popup in razor

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project. I have a razor view and in razor, I'm showing some data that are getting from the Index method in my controller which its name is RequestorsController. In razor, for each row there is a link which is called "Details" and I want when the user clicks on the Details button for each row, the related id for that row passes to a method called "Details" in RequestorsController and a list of related data returns back to the razor view and displays on a Modal popup. Now I could implement the Modal popup, but my problem is I couldn't fetch the data from the controller to show on modal. I appreciate if anyone solves my problem.

```
<div id="tablecontainer" class="my-5 col-sm-12  d-flex justify-content-center">
        <table id="myDummyTable" class="table m-table mytable table-striped mb-4 col-12 dataTable table-bordered px-0 mx-0" style="box-sizing:content-box;">
            <thead>
                <tr id="headerrow">
      
                    <th>
                        requestor name
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        items requested
                    </th>
                  
                    <th>
                        operations
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                      
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.applicantID)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.requestorName)
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.requesteditemCount)
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="@item.applicantID">Details</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-apiname" class="col-form-label">name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-apiname" name="apiname">
                            <input type="hidden" id="recipient-id" name="id" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-status" class="col-form-label">status:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-status" name="status">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section scripts{
        <script>
        @{
            if (ViewBag.ModalState == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ModalState = "hide";
            }
        }
        $('#exampleModal').modal('@ViewBag.ModalState');

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var id = button.data('id');

            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-body input[name="id"]').val(id);

            $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "Requestors")/' + id, function (data) {

                modal.find('.modal-body input[name="name"]').val(data.itemName);
                modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data.requestStatus);
            });

        });
        </script>
    }
 


   public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            
                List<ItemDTO> al = new List<ItemDTO>();

                ItemDTO apDTO;
                

                var myquery = (from t in _context.Items
                               where t.ApplicantId == id
                               select new { ItemName = t.ItemName, requestStatus = t.LastRequestStatus }).ToList();



                foreach (var index in myquery)
                {
                    apDTO = new ItemDTO();

                    apDTO.itemName = index.itemName;
                    apDTO.requestStatus = index.requestStatus;

                    al.Add(apDTO);
                }
                return View(al);
            }
```

Comment: You need to write event on button click then you need to get `data-id` of that button and then pass same to ajax and show in modal.I don't have much knowledge of asp.net but make sure you are receiving right data from backend .

Comment: I think I did what you mentioned in my code. But I don't know why modal doesn't show the data

Comment: here `input[name="name"]` should be `input[name="apiname"]` .Also did you check  what does `data` has in it ?

Comment: Thanks, after debugging I saw the error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()  Requestors/Details"

Answer (score 0):

> Now I could implement the Modal popup, but my problem is I couldn't
> fetch the data from the controller to show on modal.

As mentioned in your comment, when you click on the Details button, a 500 error occurs,I did reproduce this mistake.

**This is because the Details action returns the `View` instead of the json data that needs to be returned in ajax**, and because there is no Details view, a 500 error occurs.

To solve it, you only need to change the content of the Details action returned to **Json data**, as shown below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {

            List<ItemDTO> al = new List<ItemDTO>();

                ItemDTO apDTO;
                

                var myquery = (from t in _context.Items
                               where t.ApplicantId == id
                               select new { ItemName = t.ItemName, requestStatus = t.LastRequestStatus }).ToList();



                foreach (var index in myquery)
                {
                    apDTO = new ItemDTO();

                    apDTO.itemName = index.ItemName;// here is ItemName(case sensitive)
                    apDTO.requestStatus = index.requestStatus;

                    al.Add(apDTO);
                }
            return Json(al);
        }
```

My doubt is that if the `ApplicantId` is the **key**, then the count of data obtained from the Items table must be **one**, without the need for a list collection, but because you return a collection data, then in ajax, you need to pass **`data[0]`** to bind the corresponding input value/

And you need to change `input[name="name"]` to `input[name="apiname"]`.

Here is ajax code:

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "Requestors")/' + id, function (data) {

                modal.find('.modal-body input[name="apiname"]').val(data[0].itemName);
                modal.find('.modal-body input[name="status"]').val(data[0].requestStatus);
            });
```